# How to programatically change the routing to add my own "filter" by keyword

Tags: symfony, shopware6

My case is the following:
I have a Shopware Bundle and i need to change/extend the routing in such a way that if a request URL contains a keyword "xyz", the request is forwarded to a controller in my bundle without checking further if the route is available in "static routes" for example.

For instance: "/xyz/1/lorem/3" or "/xyz/5/3/ipsum" etc. all need to be rerouted to the controller in my bundle, since they contain the keyword /xyz.

Is there a service i can overwrite/decorate or something similar where i can implement this behaviour?

Comment: will xyz always be the first "fragment" like in your question?

Comment: yes, good question! that is in fact the case. lets assume xyz is the "starting point", everything after xyz/..... should then be rerouted accordingly to my controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a placeholder in your route with a default and a requirement allowing for all characters:

```php
/**
 * @Route("/xyz{anything}", name="frontend.my.action", methods={"GET"}, defaults={"anything"=""}, requirements={"anything"=".+"})
 */
public function myAction(Request $request): Response
{
    $anything = $request->get('anything');
    // ...
}
```

This will match any url starting with `/xyz` and every set of characters that follows afterwards is considered to be part of `anything`.